# Log4Net does not log 100% of the time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, logging, log4net

I am having some issues getting log4net to log everything I tell it to.  It seems that it really depends on where I put my `log.Info()` call; if I put it in the right place, it works, other times it does not.

Here is my config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
        </configSections>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
            <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
        </appSettings>
        <log4net>
            <root>
                <level value="ALL" />
                <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender" />
            </root>
            <appender name="rollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
                <file value="C:\binoptics\VICLogs\VICLog.txt" />
                <appendToFile value="true" />
                <rollingStyle value="Size" />
                <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
                <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
                <staticLogFileName value="true" />
                 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                     <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level - %message - %exception - %newline" />
                 </layout>
             </appender>
         </log4net>
         <system.web>
             <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
                 <providers>
                     <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
                 </providers>
             </membership>
             <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider">
                 <providers>
                     <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
                 </providers>
             </roleManager>
         </system.web>
         <startup>
             <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
         </startup>
</configuration>
```

Here is the client class that calls the log.Info() method:

In usings:

```
using System.Reflection;
using log4net;
```

In my field declarations:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

The calling method (This works perfectly):

```
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Hello " + LoginManager.CurrentUserData[1].ToString() + "!\n\n" +
        "Welcome to the BinOptics Visual Inspection Console.",
        "Login Successful!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    WaferTrackerWindow wtw = new WaferTrackerWindow();
    wtw.Show();
    log.Info(
        LoginManager.CurrentUserData[1].ToString() +
        " has successfully logged in. ");
    return "Exit";
```

The way I had it before (This does NOT work):

```
    log.Info(
        LoginManager.CurrentUserData[1].ToString() +
        " has successfully logged in. ");
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Hello " + LoginManager.CurrentUserData[1].ToString() + "!\n\n" +
        "Welcome to the BinOptics Visual Inspection Console.",
        "Login Successful!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
    WaferTrackerWindow wtw = new WaferTrackerWindow();
    wtw.Show();
    return "Exit";
```

In this second example, no exceptions are thrown at all, the log.Info() call does not work though.  I have even placed a breakpoint on the log.Info() line; it breaks right at that call, everything executes alright, but then I check my log file and that line was never written.

In this specific example, I am lucky because I have some flexibility of place the log.Info() call; in other classes in this same project, I don't have that kind of flexibility and the call can only be in one specific location.

What is going on here?  Is there anyway I can fix this?  Do I need to flush the file after each write?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Regards,

Kyle

Comment: The only thing I can think is that because showing messageboxes is a modal operation, you may have something going on that isn't completed by the time you try to log. So in your broken example, maybe the log isn't ready, or CurrentUserData is null because it's asynchronous?

Comment: 'In this second example, no exceptions are thrown at all'. This is to be expected as Log4net should never throw any exception, even when it fails. You need to enable log4net's internal logging to see why if and why it is failing.

Comment: Where are you configuring log4net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is happening is that MessageBox.Show() is blocking your thread.  If you absolutely need a popup, you should try to create a non-modal dialog to replace MessageBox.Show()

In my personal opinion, I dislike having to click on anything to continue use of a program, so I would replace this with a NotifyIcon or something like it and display the message on that.